# Запуск своего приложения по фиксированной функциональной кнопке

Tags: windows, winapi, драйвер

На ноутбуке, как и на стационарном компьютере, имеется кнопка запуска стандартных приложений (например, Media Center). После переустановки  Windows остается кнопка с установленным на нее драйвером.

Собственно вопрос: каким способом можно запустить свою программу при нажатии этой кнопки? Проблема "висит" уже второй год! Поиск по Гуглу, реестру и форумам, к сожалению, ни чего не дал.

Возможные (на мой взгляд) решения проблемы:

1. Запись пути к своей программе в реестр (как `HKLM/Software/microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run`).
2. Прямое обращение к драйверу устройства.

Comment: Вопрос не в тему, но если надо - копайте в сторону Key Manager - ов

Comment: Насколько я понимаю - драйвер для мультимедиа кнопок обычно устанавливается вместе с какими-то фирменными утилитами, которые должны этими кнопками запускаться. Тогда можно предположить, что раз эти сами утилиты можно установить в разные места, то и драйвер не должен быть "привязан" к какому-то .exe-файлу по какому-то конкретному пути. А значит, где-то все эти пути лежат (может и в реестре). Но это чисто предположения.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перехватить сообщение о нажатии конкретной кнопки. В Интернете куча информации. Например [здесь](http://devels.ru/index.php?what=art&p=385).